# How to make Android Webview support `hover` state like desktop browsers?

Tags: android, browser, hover, android-webview

If I use `:hover` in css, the element turns to hover state when I touch it, but when my finger leaves the screen, the element didn't go back to normal state.

Is there any way to make it act like in desktop browsers?

Should I customize js `touchstart` `touchend` event to every touch event?

Comment: I don't know much about css, but I know my Galaxy note can simulate the hover event with the special pen. You really have to hover the screen. So it is a different action than an actual touch.

Comment: @Aloong I know that your question is old, but today, in 2018, I am facing the same problem! Did you find a solution for it?